# Working with C/C++ preprocessor macros in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

There can be a macro definition *somewhere* in my project:

`#define A 1`

In another place of my project, there are such piece of code:

`#ifdef A`

`do_something()`

`#endif`

When I move mouse pointer to "ifdef" Visual Studio 2010 IDE shows "#define A 2".

That is fine, but how can I understand, in which file VS seeing this macro definition?

Comment: Right click on the `A` in `#ifdef A` and select "Go To Definition". It will take you right there.

Comment: Many things suck badly about macros.  The inability of the IntelliSense parser to figure out which is the actual definition is certainly one of them.  It doesn't stand much of a chance.

Answer (score 0):

It is being pulled from a data structure inside MSVC

As you type and create data types and macros and function, MSVC adds that information to an 
internal symbol table.  When you hover over an identifier, it does a lookup on it and then can display the information as you see it.